# String Replace windows location

Tags: javascript

I tried to replace the windows.location ex:

My windows location is http:// and i need to replace in https, this code return "undefinied" value, why?

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var windost = window.location;
var opens = windost.replace("http","https");
alert(opens);
}
</script>
```

Comment: The simple replace() will produce a flaw. check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
function myFunction()
{
    var windost = window.location.href;
    var opens = windost.replace("http","https");
    alert(opens);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`location` isn't a string, so its `replace` method doesn't act in the same way as the `replace`method that is available on strings. You want `location.href`, which is a string.

```
var windost = location.href;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this it will solve your problem

```
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        var windost = window.location.toString();
        var opens = windost.replace("http", "https");
        alert(opens);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `toString()` function (or better the `href` as suggested by Quentin), and combine it with an `if` to avoid bad replacing.

```
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {       
        if (window.location.protocol == "http:") {
          var opens = window.location.href.replace("http://", "https://")
          alert(opens);    
        }      
    }
    myFunction()
</script>
```

**Details:**
Your old replace, even if fixed will make some bad replacing, for example:

- The location already starts with *https* (will produce something like httpss://link.com)
- The location with http word inside the URL

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/EyE5K/2/) is an example.